# How come an answer linking to a -2 answer gets 5 votes?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

See [How can I test authlogic's current_user in Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869753/how-can-i-test-authlogics-current-user-in-cucumber/1235329#1235329)

It's not very helpful at all.

Comment: Its strange, but voting is not 100% logic. It could be friends, or people not following the link. Or maybe they really thought it was helpful.

Comment: Some people enjoyed seeing the downvoted answer, so upvoted him for providing that.

Comment: Fixed.  The link now points to the question.  I've left a comment as well to help the user understand that answering with a link is less than helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am of the strong opinion that answers which essentially are:

> The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com)

should be converted to comments.  It is NOT an answer.  For users with the right to, the failure to flag as dupe is especially egregious.

Comment: I come across these quite often, but don't flag them. Are you saying I should flag as "not an answer"?

Comment: @ire_and_curses: Yes.  "Not an answer" flags are usually spot on and easy to deal with.  Of course, "Should be a comment on the question" would be even better a comment on the flag.

Answer (score 2):

He intended to link to the question itself, not his answer - as the question got Accepted Answer it also help the other case.

He probably posted that +5 answer shortly after the -2 (now -3) answer so he copied the full URL which link to the answer he just posted.

I considered editing the answer and remove the `#1235261` from his link but think it's inappropriate as it was posted long time ago.

Comment: I had no problem with that since the link text is `question`, not `answer`.

Comment: I know, but it's still confusing. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the technical details of the post in question so I can just answer in a general case.  Main causes that I see are either:

- That his answer is appropriate to this question but not to the original question that it received -2 from.
- That people aren't paying attention and up-voted an answer without looking at the link.

Comment: hmm probably the second one, but looking at the comments, it seems the answerer was also unsuccessful with what the OP was asking.